# How do i adjust ImageView if it falls outside of view Switcher bounds?

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, viewswitcher

[image: hhh]

i have view switcher(it contains 2 views of kettle - on and off)

the first image is kettle "off" , and it stays outside of actual viewSwitcher.

**I tried fitXY, fixStart, fitCenter - did not help!**
Below is the layout of viewSwitcher
[image: kkk]

I already tried to change the size of kettle image itself - it does not help

How do i make it stay in bounds of the view Switcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you imageView scaleType centerInside and set adjustViewBounds as true

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply this to your ImageView

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

If it's not scaled properly with fitXY, change it to this

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```